# How to display post title in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to generate the wordpress post title in the following javascript code:  I'm placing this code under the content in my wordpress posts.

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://adn.ebay.com/cb?programId=1&campId=5337203820&toolId=10026&customId=posttop&keyword=**POST-TITLE**&width=728&height=90&font=1&textColor=000000&linkColor=0000AA&arrowColor=8BBC01&color1=709AEE&color2=[COLORTWO]&format=ImageLink&contentType=TEXT_AND_IMAGE&enableSearch=y&usePopularSearches=n&freeShipping=n&topRatedSeller=y&itemsWithPayPal=n&descriptionSearch=n&showKwCatLink=n&excludeCatId=&excludeKeyword=&catId=177913%2C179767%2C1059&disWithin=200&ctx=n&autoscroll=n&flashEnabled=' + isFlashEnabled + '&pageTitle=' + _epn__pageTitle + '&cachebuster=' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000 )) + '">\x3C/script>' );
```

The **keyword=** part of the script is where I need to generate the wordpress post title.   I was trying `keyword="<?php single_post_title(); ?>"` but it doesn't generate the wordpress post title... not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Any help would be appreciated. Please remember I'm a newbie. If I forgot to mention something please ask.  I'll be quick to respond.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show the PHP code! The rendered HTML does not help at all. You should better post your question on the WordPress StackExchange site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Show what PHP code? I asked it over there...

Comment: WordPress is PHP. So I'd like to see the code that you wrote to create the HTML you have in the OP. You can only use the `<?php /* ... */ ?>` in PHP files so I assume there is more code than that.

Comment: where are you doing this? if single_post_title() fails you are not in a single post loop or there is no title set.

Comment: @Julian - The php code was my weak attempt.  This javascript code is going under the content in my wordpress posts.

Comment: @David - I'm placing the javascript code under the content of my wp posts.  Excuse my lack of coding skills... are you saying keyword="<?php single_post_title(); ?>" should work if I'm in the loop?

Comment: yes i answered with a method for what you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your loop see `if ( have_posts() )`  and `while`, use this inside the `while` statement.

```
$title= get_the_title();
```

Now the variable is set, you can use it later unless it is overwritten.

in your js:

```
keyword="<?php echo $title; ?>"
```

Comment: That works great but I have one slight issue I ran into.  I need the spaces in the title to be + (plus sign) with no spaces.  Can you help me with this? So instead the results would look like keyword="Capture+the+Moment" instead of keyword="Capture the Moment". Maybe a filter to remove space and replace with + sign? Thank you so much.  This helps a lot!

Comment: `$title=str_replace(' ','+', get_the_title() );`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.  You explained everything perfectly so a newbie like me could understand. Thank you, truly!

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do it for blog posts and normal pages. Here it is:

```php
<?php the_title(); ?>
```